# How to set an environment variable in Jenkins DSL using the Credentials Binding plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have created a credential in Jenkins called `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`. I have the "Credentials Binding Plugin" installed.

If I create a Job manually in the UI I am able to select the Binding I would like for the Environment and select my Secret Text type.

I want to replicate this in my Jobs DSL script. I have found the following snippet which is *very* close to what I want to do:

```
job('example-2') {
    wrappers {
        credentialsBinding {
            usernamePassword('PASSWORD', 'jarsign-keystore')
        }
    }
}
```

However the credential I want to inject is Secret Text and I cannot find what the function to it with is, e.g. instead of `usernamePassword`. Does anyone know what this should be please?

Comment: Go through the official documentation of the plugin [Credentials Binding JobDSL](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-wrappers-credentialsBinding). Here there are different functions to inject credentials either file, string, usernamePassword, zipFile

Comment: @Suresh Thank you for the link, I was not able to find it yesterday

Comment: would this set the checkbox Build Environment -> Use secret text(s) or file(s) automatically? I am trying to do the same and the checkbox is never set, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

'Secret text' kind credentials are retrieved as 'string()' in the credentialBinding context.

For example:

```
job('example') {
    wrappers {
        credentialsBinding {
            string('SECRETWORD', 'name_of_credential')
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation at: https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.wrapper.WrapperContext.credentialsBinding

Comment: So does the above example mean their will be an environment variable named "SECRETWORD" that will contain the value of the name_of_credential binding and the SECRETWORD environment variable will be accessible in a shell() step?